# Ping an open Node connection without sending data

Tags: node.js, http, express

I need to keep a connection alive. I am using GoRouter through a third party vendor. I have no way to modify it. The only way to keep the connection alive is by physically sending data through connection. I am able to do that by doing a `res.write(' ');`. I don't like this solution though because it just ends up that I write a bunch of extra spaces to the output. It is not very neat. I tried to do `res.write('')`, but I think node does not actually write when there is nothing to write. Setting the keep-alive header does not work, because GoRouter will only keep a connection alive if it sees data passing through it.

Is there any way to send empty data?

I was thinking maybe there is a http ping? Something like `res.ping()`